# How to download single raw file from private gitlab repo using username and password

Tags: curl, gitlab, wget

I can clone a private repo with username & password using command below

```sh
git clone https://some-git-lab-token:someHash@git.xxx.com/foo/bar.git
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to `curl` or `wget` a single raw file from the same repo using the same credential `some-git-lab-token:someHash`

A sample gitlab raw file url as below

```js
https://gitlab.com/athos.oc/lodash-has-plugin/-/raw/master/.eslintrc.json
```

I've tried to curl a single file as below but failed

```sh
curl https://some-git-lab-token:someHash@git.xxx.com/foo/bar/-/raw/master/testing.js
```

The result that I got is as below

```html
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://git.xxx.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Comment: This can be achieved with the help of Personal Access token. Can you make use of that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To download a repository file through curl, you need to use the [repository files API endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository).

Using your example `https://gitlab.com/athos.oc/lodash-has-plugin/-/raw/master/.eslintrc.json`, would turn into:

`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/30349314/repository/files/%2Eeslintrc%2Ejson/raw?ref=master`

However, [API authentication](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#authentication) does not include username and password as an available authentication method, so you would need to use a token (or a session cookie).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For future reference, you will still need `/raw` to have the content because without it you are only getting metadata of the file. So the link should be `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/30349314/repository/files/%2Eeslintrc%2Ejson/raw?ref=master`

Comment: oh yes, sorry! I copied the wrong example from the docs. I've updated the link and the example